# How to use :hover affects to child element?

Tags: sass

I have this html structure:

```
.Gallery > .Gallery__container > .Gallery__container-item > .Gallery__container-item-image
```

I want to `:hover` on `.Gallery__container-item` affects to `.Gallery__container-item-image`

```
  &-item{
      background-color: $darkgray;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:hover{
        &-image{ //doesn't recognized
          transition: scale 1s linear;
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }
      }
    }
```

Using `SCSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand `&` in your code will not compile to what you want.
**Here is a simplified example (with less markup and less styling):**

```
.Gallery {
    &-item {
        &:hover {
            &-image {
                transition: scale 1s linear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**will compile to:**

```
.Gallery-item:hover-image {
  transition: scale 1s linear;
}
```

Now, you have few possibilities, first one would be to write the full class name:

```
.Gallery {
    &-item {
        &:hover {
            .Gallery-item-image {
                transition: scale 1s linear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also define a variable that will take the value of the selector before the `:hover`, that's probably what you want to do:

```
.Gallery {
    &-item {
        $selector : &;
        &:hover {
            #{$selector}-image {
                transition: scale 1s linear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```